# use weight transfer learning trained in customer data after training in another customer data

Tags: deep-learning, transfer-learning

I hope you are well I have a question can I train transfer learning like pre-trained model 'vgg16' trained on ImageNet in my customer data and save weight to train another customer data?
How I can do this, please
Thanks for ur time

Comment: Of cause you can do that. Depend on your framework you use. Now, almost frameworks support load pre-trained weight by its parameter

Comment: thanks for ur time, can u give me example code?

Answer (score 0):

I do example with [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/) framework.
When you train any model, you have to define training strategy.
There are two ways to save and load trained weight for transfer learning in Pytorch.

---

The first is `load state dict` - only save and load the weight (paramemters) (recommended).
While training, if condition you defined satisfied, let's save the trained weight by this command ([refer link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended))

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

And then when you train VGG16 model with other custom dataset and want to transfer learning from previous trained weight, use this

```
model = VGG16(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

---

The second way is load the whole model (model structure included)
To save model, use ([refer link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-entire-model))

```
torch.save(model, PATH)
```

And to load it

```
# Model class must be defined somewhere
model = torch.load(PATH)
model.eval()
```

You can refer some links [[1](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)], [[2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-my-pretrained-vgg-weight/36590)]